# How do create a global method in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, global

I am trying to refactor my code, using a POST request to a url, parsing JSON and doing a lot of useful stuff. Unfortunately I need to use it multiple times in multiple view controllers. What would be the best approach to make this happen ?

I have found a working solutions for variables ( global variables used in every VC ). 
.m file looks like :

```
#import "DataClass.h"

@implementation DataClass
@synthesize str;
@synthesize credits;
@synthesize points;
@synthesize globalName;
@synthesize questionsCount;
@synthesize wrongQuestionsCount;
@synthesize correctQuestionsCount;

static DataClass *instance = nil;

+(DataClass *)getInstance
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance= [DataClass new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

And each time i call a data class object using the getInstance method to use/modify a variable.
The method now gets few NSString params and also returns an NSString .

SO my question is .. can I use the same class for making my callPostURL method global and available for every VC in my app ?
Should I use the DataClass or there's a better solution ?

Comment: that is absolutely normal to use a singleton class for handling the model layer and its related tasks – I would not recommend to use the solution which shows up in @David's answer, that is a quite messy for such situation.

Comment: Yes..even looking at the comments(knowing it's not right) I tried using it and it gave me two of my favorite ( LINK O MATCHER ) erros which i could not fix... so I will be waiting for a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an inline static method to have it available everywhere.

In your AppDelegate.h for example, create a function like this and you can use it everywhere.

```
static inline BOOL myTestMethod(NSString *aString, NSInteger anInteger) {
    ...
}
```

Then in your implementations, you call it like this : `BOOL rep = myTestMethod(@"foo", 1);`
Don't forget to #import your header in the files you want to use the function.

Comment: the pch file is removed in Xcode 6 by default and for good reason, you shouldnt be putting global functions or properties in here - do not use it as a junk drawer as its bad practice and becomes difficult to maintain as well as greatly slowing down your compilation time